Как принудить Minecraft обновить чанки?
Я ищу способ как можно принудить Minecraft обновить чанки. Допусти интерпретировать сочетание клавиш a+f3. Однако, я хочу внешне воздействовать на игру и обновить чанки вокруг игрока (то есть меня). Скажите, кто знает по какой причине могут обновиться чанки вокруг игрока? Можно ли как то это симулировать извне? Я имею ввиду воздействовать каким-то методом на игру саму и чтоб она посчитала что сейчас нужно эти чанки обновить. Без модов только пожалуйста
